# Translate below Rank() Spotfire expression into Dax query

Tags: powerbi, dax, spotfire, spotfire-analyst

How to convert the below Spotfire expression into a DAX query?

```
Rank(RowId(),"asc",[ACT_ID],[REPORT_END],[ACTIVITY_END_DATE]
```

Comment: Better provide more inform, such as image, else it is hard to know what is the expected output

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rank something use:

https://dax.guide/rankx/

```
 RankMeasure = RANKX (
        'TableNameHere',
        [YourMeasureToRankOn],
        [OrderOn], ASC/DESC

    )
```

Comment: It's giving me error for multiple columns

Comment: You can propably use "&" for concatenate multiple columns (and sorting as one).
I never use spotfire, maybe I miss how its work. Can you add sample data (source) and desired result?